# call my API (typescript) with my frontend application in VUE3 Js

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, typescript2.0

hey  i develloped an Api rest in nodejs and i 'd like now consume it but i've always the same strange error.
i've never used vue before, moreover i'm using Vue3 which is recent.
Hey here is my code from my vue3Js frontend application and i've the same error whatever i do:

products.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import RestaurantService from "@/services/RestaurantService";
import Restaurant from "@/types/restaurant";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "restaurants-list",
  data() {
    return {
      restaurants: [] as Restaurant[],
      currentRestaurant: {} as Restaurant,
      currentIndex: -1,
      title: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    retrieveRestaurants() {
      RestaurantService.getAllRestaurant()
        .then((response: Restaurant[]) => {
          this.restaurants = response;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((e: Error) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retrieveRestaurants();
  },
});
</script>
```

---

RestaurantService.ts

```
import Restaurant from "@/models/Restaurant";
import axios from "axios"

class RestaurantService {
    async getAllRestaurant(): Promise<Array<Restaurant>> {
                const { data } = await axios.get<Array<Restaurant>>(
                    'http://localhost:3000/micros/restaurant',
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/json',
                        },
                    },
                );
        
                return data;
            }
        }

export default new RestaurantService();
```

---

restaurant.ts (type)

```
export default interface restaurant {
  name: string,
  category: String,
  adress : String
  articles: Array<Article>
}
 
  interface Article {
      _id: number,
      name: string,
      price: number,
      description:string,
      src:string,
  }
```

---

Restaurant.ts (model)

```
export default interface restaurant {
    name: string,
    category: String,
    adress : String
    articles: Array<Article>
}
   
    interface Article {
        _id: number,
        name: string,
        price: number,
        description:string,
        src:string,
    }

  export default interface ResponseData {
        data: any;
      }
```

i've followed the vue3js but i have these errors :

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                   16:13:06

error  in ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   data() {
|     return {
>       restaurants: [] as Restaurant[],
|       currentRestaurant: {} as Restaurant,
|       currentIndex: -1,

error  in ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=template&id=7177119e&scoped=true&ts=true

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| ], -1 /* HOISTED */))
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   const _component_v_col = _resolveComponent("v-col")!
|

ERROR in ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts) 10:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   data() {
|     return {
>       restaurants: [] as Restaurant[],
|       currentRestaurant: {} as Restaurant,
|       currentIndex: -1,
@ ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 1:0-130 1:0-130 1:131-250 1:131-250
@ ./src/views/Products.vue 2:0-59 3:0-54 3:0-54 8:49-55
@ ./src/router/index.js 3:0-45 18:13-21
@ ./src/main.js 3:0-30 4:19-25

ERROR in ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=template&id=7177119e&scoped=true&ts=true (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=template&id=7177119e&scoped=true&ts=true) 48:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
* ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| ], -1 /* HOISTED */))
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   const _component_v_col = _resolveComponent("v-col")!
|
@ ./src/views/Products.vue?vue&type=template&id=7177119e&scoped=true&ts=true 1:0-219 1:0-219
@ ./src/views/Products.vue 1:0-89 8:68-74 18:88-20:3 19:29-35 18:2-20:4
@ ./src/router/index.js 3:0-45 18:13-21
@ ./src/main.js 3:0-30 4:19-25

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Comment: The thing that happens is your setup and config. You didn't even mention if you use Vue CLI or Vite.

Comment: i'm using vue CLI

Comment: Have you tried newer versions of typescript?

Comment: Also, you don't define `Restaurant` in the code you have provided, only `restaurant`.